# What happened to Primary Administrator profile in Solaris 11?

Tags: permissions, solaris

What happened to the "Primary Administrator" profile in Solaris 11?  Why was it cut?  Are there any alternatives?

How does it differ from the root-role (which is `profiles=All;auths=solaris.*`)

Is the less powerful "System Administrator" better?  Why?  Reason to use/not use either/both?

On my system, I "re-created" it by adding entries in `/etc/security/prof_attr.d` and `/etc/security/exec_attr.d...`  However Solaris 11 lacks the solaris.grant (`auths=solaris.all,solaris.grant;exec=uid=0,gid=0`)... Is grant no longer needed?  Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This profile was removed for granting unlimited privileges while not requiring a password. The alternative is simply to use `sudo`.

Comment: And for running all commands with full privileges without any discretion in any code path in which RBAC was used, causing unexpected use of root in some cases (like in GNOME with profile aware menu launchers).